# How to import audio into R on a mac?

Tags: r, macos, audio

I have recently changed from a PC to a mac, and have trouble trying to input my recorded audio into R.

On the PC the audio needed to be in 'My Documents' for the `tuneR` package to find my audio using:

```
readWave('audio.wav')
```

However I am having trouble finding the right directory that the audio needs to be on the mac for R to find it.

So far I have my audio file copied into every folder, but still no luck.

Comment: You are incorrect that the audio files needed to be in "My Documents."  My guess is that you were running `R` in that directory (a bad idea in itself).  Before you get into deeper trouble with `R`,  I strongly recommend you get some training in handling files and directories on a computer (regardless of the operating system).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I know it's old news; I wish I had said this before: Your comment is obnoxious and as unhelpful as can be. Before you annoy more people and further perpetuate the bad programmer stereotypes, I strongly recommend you work on your interpersonal skills.

Comment: @mattyTpain  First of all, I'm not a programmer, nor do I rate software jocks as some sort of uber-aspergers group.  My comment here was intended to get the OP to recognize that there are shortcomings in her understanding of computers and software that will not be alleviated by some simple answer like yours.  I've tried that (online and off), and invariably the person comes back with exactly the same type of problem related to some other app or document the next day.  Give a man a fish, etc.   HAND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio can be in whatever directory you like, you just have to tell R exactly where it is.  Try writing out the full path to the file, e.g. `readWave('/Users/EmmaL/audiofiles/audio.wav')`.  To find out the path, look up the file in Finder, right click, select `Get Info`, and check out General -> Where: